# Angular 2 - ngOnInit method not being invoked

Tags: angular, ngoninit

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteData, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'response',
  templateUrl: 'app/templates/response.html'
})

export class ResponseComponent implements OnInit {
  searchResult = {};
  constructor(routeData: RouteData) {
    this.searchResult = routeData.get('searchResult');
    console.log(this.searchResult);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('in init');
    console.log(this.searchResult);
  }

}
```

I am routing to this component from parent component but this.searchResult is not getting set to be used in the template, also ngOnInit() method is not invoked.

I am able to get route data in the constructor and it is printing when i console logged.

Comment: You get no console errors? I would start by removing your unused imports to narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: no, its not even coming to the ngOnInit(), i am not getting the console.log  in that?

Comment: How is the component added to the DOM?